# EmailDialog not closing when send or even cancelling

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, core-data, email-attachments

i want to send an email, but when i click on send it really sends that email but the view is not closed.

MainViewController.m

```
NSString *text = [self fetchLogCoreData];
PlistCreatorViewController *plistCreator = [[PlistCreatorViewController alloc] init];
[plistCreator sendPlist2Email:self text:text];
```

I'm fetching all data in coreData and then put it into an NSString.
Then call sendPlist2Email with self as the view and text as the text i want to use in email.

PlistCreatorViewController.m

```
 -(void)sendPlist2Email: (UIViewController*) viewController text:(NSString*)text{

    NSString *emailTitle = @"PickDPack App: DATA";

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:text isHTML:NO];

    // Determine the file name and extension

    // Get the resource path and read the file using NSData
    // Add attachment

    [viewController presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    MainViewController *mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    // Close the Mail Interface
    NSLog(@"Email_out");
    [mainView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Really simple, im sending the email but the window doesn't close when i press send/cancel.

I've tried to put `self`into `[mainView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];` changing `mainView`but nothing change.

I've put this code inside `MainViewController.m`but nothing change.

I hope anyone could help me :S

Thx

Comment: Have you tried replacing `mainView` with `controller` in the modal dismiss?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried as like below?

```
- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
      [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, when I click on cancel or Send the app crashes and send me here when running in Xcode: `return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));`